# Django :There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table"

Tags: python, django

There are countless questions related to this error, but after over a month I've still not been able to solve this problem, since in my setup there is in fact a unique constraint. I have already asked this question before, but the answer was to add a unique field to my model which *IS* already present.

I'm running an older django version, 1.7.11, and circumstances do not allow me to upgrade.

I have a Photo class, which contains multiple foreign keys to other classes.

```
class Photo(UserBase):
    """
    Photograph
    """

scene_category = models.ForeignKey(
        SceneCategory, related_name='photos', null=True, blank=True)
artist = models.ForeignKey(
        Artist, related_name='photos', null=True, blank=True)
gallery = models.ForeignKey(
        Gallery, related_name='photos', null=True, blank=True)
```

The inheritance for `UserBase`

```
class UserBase(ModelBase):

    #: User that created this object
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-id']

class ModelBase(EmptyModelBase):
    """ Base class of all models, with an 'added' field """
    added = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-id']

class EmptyModelBase(models.Model):
    """ Base class of all models, with no fields """

    def get_entry_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.id}

    def get_entry_attr(self):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
        return 'data-model="%s/%s" data-id="%s"' % (
            ct.app_label, ct.model, self.id)

    def get_entry_id(self):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
        return '%s.%s.%s' % (ct.app_label, ct.model, self.id)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Additionally, there also already multiple classes that contain a foreign key to `Photo`. All of these work perfectly.

```
class SubstanceExistsLabel(PhotoLabelBase):
    """ Label indicating whether or not a substance is present in an image """

    #: photo being labeled
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='substance_exists_labels')

    #: all points should have this substance
    substance = models.ForeignKey(SubstanceCategory)

class SubstancePointsLabel(ResultBase):
    """ List of points in an image that should have a certain substance """

    #: photo being labeled
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='substance_points_labels')

    #: all points should have this substance
    substance = models.ForeignKey(SubstanceCategory)

class SubstancePoint(EmptyModelBase):
    """ A single point in a photo being considered for its substance """

    #: photo
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='substance_points')
```

Each `Photo` instance contains the default unique id.

```
>>> Photo.objects.all()[0].id
    5960
```

Now my problem. I'm trying to create another class `Material` shown below, which contains a foreign key to `Photo`, just as `SubstanceExistsLabel`, `SubstancePointsLabel` and `SubstancePoint` already do, as well as multiple other classes.

```
class Material(models.Model):
    #: photo being labeled
    original = models.ForeignKey(
        Photo, related_name='pictures',null=True,blank=True
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    asked = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    yes = models.IntegerField(default=None)
```

Yet, each time I try to migrate, this gives me the error 
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "photos_photo"`. Full stack trace added below.

Either I still do not understand what this errors means, or there is already a unique constraint for the referenced table, since I am able to create other classes with a foreign key to `Photo`. How can I create this class? Or otherwise is there a work-around to create a one-to-many relationship where one `Photo` has multiple `Material` instances?

*full stack trace*

```
    Applying points.0014_auto_20180124_0528...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 91, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/data_nfs/opensurfaces2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "photos_photo"
```

Comment: instead of `original = models.ForeignKey(
        Photo.id, related_name='pictures',null=True,blank=True
    )` why not `original = models.ForeignKey(Photo)`? And 1 more suggestion that might help is (DO AT OWN risk, and BACKUP the DB), reset the whole DB and then `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Hope this helps

Comment: Originally I intended it to be to `Photo`, not `Photo.id` but in desperation I tried everything I could think of. Changed it back to reflect original intention.